# Embedded Jetty 9: how to use JSP, Servlets and WebSockets toguether

Tags: jsp, servlets, websocket, jetty

I'm moving from Tomcat to Jetty, therefore I have a very limited Jetty knowledge, sorry. And I need to run Jetty in embedded mode (started form inside my application).

I use basically JSP with EL, Servlets and WebSockets.
I have already working the JSPs and Servlets, and I know how to run WebSockets, but I can not find the way to do all toguether.

This is  simplified version of the code I'm currently using.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

---

```
private static Server server = null;

public static void startup()
{
    WebAppContext ctx = new WebAppContext();
                  ctx.setContextPath( Config.getContextPath() );

    initServer( ctx );
    initWebSockets();
    initServlets( ctx );
    initJSPs( ctx );
    server.start();
}

private static void initServer( WebAppContext ctx ) throws Exception
{
    server = new Server( Config.getWebPort() );
    server.setHandler( ctx );
    server.setStopAtShutdown( true );
}

private static void initWebSockets() throws Exception
{
    ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS );
                          sch.setContextPath( Config.getContextPath() );
    ServerContainer wsContainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext( ctx );
                    wsContainer.addEndpoint( EventSocket.class );
}

private static void initServlets( WebAppContext ctx ) throws Exception
{
    ctx.addServlet( GetFile.class, "/getfile" );
}

private static void initJSPs( WebAppContext ctx ) throws Exception
{
    ctx.setResourceBase( "webui" );
    ctx.setDescriptor( "web.xml" );

    System.setProperty( "org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "false" );

    File fTmp = new File( System.getProperty( "java.io.tmpdir" ), "jetty-jsp-tmp" );
    if( ! UtilIO.createFolder( fTmp ) )
    {
        throw new IOException( "Can not create folder '"+ fTmp.getAbsolutePath() +"'" );
    }
    ctx.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", fTmp );

    ClassLoader jspClassLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[0], WebServer.class.getClassLoader() );
    ctx.setClassLoader( jspClassLoader );

    ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder( "jsp", JspServlet.class );
                  holderJsp.setInitOrder( 0 );

    ServletHolder holderDefault = new ServletHolder( "default", DefaultServlet.class );
                  holderDefault.setInitParameter( "resourceBase", ctx.getContextPath() );
                  holderDefault.setInitParameter( "dirAllowed", "false" );
    ctx.addServlet( holderDefault, "/" );

    ctx.setAttribute( "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/[^/]*jstl.*\\.jar$" );

    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault( server );

    classlist.addBefore( "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                         "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration" );

    classlist.addAfter( "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
                        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
                        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration" );
}
```

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: Hello Joakim: as I mention in the title "Jetty 9" (version is 9).
And thank you very much for your interest in my question.

Comment: Not specific enough.  Within "Jetty 9.x" there's 5 major version releases. (yes, I do mean "major", in the Jetty sense)

Comment: Hello again Joakim: version is 9.4.0